# A group which is $\mathbb{Z}$-by-finite but not finite-by-$\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found a lemma which states:

> If a group $G$ is finite-by-$\mathbb{Z}$, then $G$ is
>   $\mathbb{Z}$-by-finite.

I was wondering if the converse is true, i.e. is it true that

> if a group G is $\mathbb{Z}$-by-finite, it's also finite-by-$\mathbb{Z}$?

I suspect not, but as I'm only starting to begin to understand the theory, I can't come up with a counterexample.

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:** A brief explanation of $\mathcal{P}$-by-$\mathcal{Q}$:  Let $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ be 2 properties of groups. Then a group $G$ is $\mathcal{P}$-by-$\mathcal{Q}$ if there exist a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $N$ has property $\mathcal{P}$ and $G/N$ has property $\mathcal{Q}$.

The line "has property $\mathbb{Z}$" means: being isomorphic to the infinite cyclic group.

Comment: Could you perhaps give a brief explanation of $A$-by-$B$?

Comment: Of course: Let $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ be 2 properties of groups. Then a group $G$ is $\mathcal{P}$-by-$\mathcal{Q}$ if there exist a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $N$ has property $\mathcal{P}$ and $G/N$ has property $\mathcal{Q}$.

Comment: How do you mean $\Bbb Z$ to be a property?

Comment: Oh, sorry: that means being isomorphic to the infinite cyclic group ($\mathbb{Z}$). I'll edit my question in order to make it more clear.

Comment: Just to check that I have gotten the P-by-Q correctly, could you say that a group is solvable iff it is (...((abelian-by-abelian)-by-abelian)...)-by-abelian for some finite number of repetitions?

Comment: @Riley the critical step in the proof of the lemma (at least in the version of the proof I was able to provide) is that the section is only guaranteed when the quotient is infinite cyclic, a finite quotient would not give you a free section to produce the semi-direct product. Further the map to the automorphism group is not guaranteed to be trivial with the two switched--this weakness is exactly what leads to the infinite dihedral counterexample in the answers as well.

Comment: @Arthur: A group is solvable iff there exists a series of subgroups $G = G_1 \triangleright G_2 \triangleright \cdots \triangleright G_n = \{1\}$ such that $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is abelian. So yes, I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be the infinite diedral group: $$G=\langle a,b\mid b^2=1, bab=a^{-1}\rangle.$$ The subgroup generated by $a$ is normal and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, the quotient is of order $2$. Hence, $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-by-finite.

However, there is no normal subgroup of $G$ which is finite. So the group is not finite-by-$\mathbb{Z}$. To see that, take a normal subgroup $H\subset G$ and a non-trivial element $h\in H$. If $h\in \langle a\rangle$, then $h$ is of infinite order, so $H$ also. Otherwise, $h=a^lb$ for some $l\in \mathbb{Z}$. You compute then $$aha^{-1}h^{-1}=a^{l+1}ba^{-1}ba^{-l}=a^{l+1}aa^{-l}=a^2\in H$$
and find again that $H$ is of infinite order.

Comment: No, the question asked "I was wondering if the converse is true, i.e. if a group G is $\mathbb{Z}$-by-finite, it's also finite-by-$\mathbb{Z}$?" and I showed that this was false, as suspected by Riley.

Comment: @Adam it seems to me that that is precisely what was asked.

Answer (score 4):

The infinite dihedral group $D := \langle x, y : y^{-1}xy = x^{-1}, y^2 = 1 \rangle$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-by finite.

Suppose $F$ is a finite normal subgroup of $D$. Then $F \cap \langle x \rangle$ is trivial so $D$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $D / \langle x \rangle \cong C_2$. If $|F| = 2$ then $F = \langle a \rangle$ for some central element $a \in D$ of order two. However the centre of $D$ is trivial, so in fact $|F| = 1$.

Thus $D$ has no non-trivial finite normal subgroups, so its only infinite homomorphic image is $D$ itself. In particular, $D$ cannot be finite-by-$\mathbb{Z}$ since $D$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (having a non-trivial element of order two).

Answer (score 2):

The dihedral group is in a sense the only exception: a group is $\mathbf{Z}$-by-finite if and only if it is finite-by-$\mathbf{Z}$ or finite-by-$D_\infty$.

Comment: A bit late to the party: do you know if the analogous statement is true if one replaces "finite" by "locally finite" ?

Comment: @Justdroppedin that's a good question, maybe better ask it separately? I'll try to think about it.